# show that $|x(t)|\le e^{(1+\epsilon)t}|x_0|$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

consider the ODE

$$x'(t)=(1+\epsilon f(t))x(t)\\
x(0)=x_0$$

where $x\in \mathbb{R},(t)\in C^1(\mathbb{R}), |f(t)|\le 1$ and $0< \epsilon <1 $

show that $|x(t)|\le e^{(1+\epsilon)t}|x_0|$

As $C^1(\mathbb{R})$

So

$\int x'(t)=\int (1+\epsilon f(t))x(t)$

here im missing something but i didn't get can anyone help

Comment: Actually, you can solve this ODE. Try to integrate $x(t)/x'(t)$.

Comment: See Gronwall lemma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note that $$(\ln|x|)'=\frac1x$$so
you can rewrite equation as $$\frac{x'(t)}{x(t)}=(1+\epsilon f(t))$$take $| | $both dsides
$$|\frac{x'(t)}{x(t)}|=|(1+\epsilon f(t))|$$now apply conditions
$$|f(t)|<1,\epsilon<1$$so
$$|(1+\epsilon f(t))|\\\leq |1|+|\epsilon f(t)|\\ \leq 1+|\epsilon| |f(t)|\\<1+\epsilon \times 1$$
now integrate both sides from $0 \to t$ over $t\in[0,1]$
$$\frac{|x'(t)|}{|x(t)|}\leq 1+\epsilon \times 1\\ \frac{d}{dt}\ln |x(t)| \leq 1+\epsilon \times 1
\\\int_0^t \frac{d}{ds}\ln |x(s)|ds \leq \int_0^t (1+\epsilon \times 1)ds\\
\ln|(x(t)|-\ln |x(0)| \leq t+\epsilon \times t \leq 1+\epsilon \times t$$

Comment: @naresh nayer: you can also use iterative Piccard method for ODE's

Answer (score 3):

Take the result and work backwards:
$$
(e^{-(1+ϵ)t}x(t))'=-ϵe^{-(1+ϵ)t}(1-f(t))<0
$$
etc.

Answer (score 1):

$\ln |x(t)|=\ln |(x(0)|+\int_0^{t} \frac {x'(t)} {x(t)}dt$ so $\ln |x(t)|\leq \ln |(x(0)|+ \int_0^{t} (1+\epsilon) dt$. Take exponential.